# Why can't I retrieve FaceBook profile pic in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, image

I am trying to retrieve my `FaceBook Profile pic` using a `Url` in Android. I am not able to retrieve any image. I have no error logs as such but I get the following Log.
`04-05 04:14:41.005: D/skia(2987): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`. I am posting the codes. Please tell me step by step what am I doing wrong.

```
   final ImageView photoImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> t = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>(){
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... p) {
       Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
                URL aURL = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/+"id"+/picture?type=small");
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                conn.setUseCaches(true);
                conn.connect(); 
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close(); 
                is.close();
               // photoImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
           return bm;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm){

               // Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
               photoImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            //  photoImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); 


        }
    };
    t.execute();
```

Comment: i thing this way will not work , because executing this URL  will redirect you to new link for image , so this link is not for direct image url it's just to get image url .

Comment: This link is for direct image url

Answer (score 0):

```
URL aURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small");
```

Try this.

And if `id` is `integer` convert to `string`

And also not `http` , try `https`

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code, This is perfectly working for me.

```
try {
        URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId()+ "/picture?type=large");
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```